# Change Data Capture(CDC) - Slowly Changing Dimension(SCD2) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here is a scenario which is as follows:

1. There is a historical data in Hive which is keep growing on daily basis.
2. Daily fresh data comes in the form of batches which is merged to the data mentioned above.
3. As of now above process is being run on Hadoop Cluster as scheduled Hive jobs.
4. Above setup is to be migrated on AWS cloud.

Now problem is how to setup the cluster:

1. If we setup continuously running EMR cluster then cost will be too high and also most of the time cluster would be unused (as data is coming in batches once or twice in a day)
2. If we use scheduled EMR cluster (instance fleet) then at the processing time we will have to copy full historical data from the storage (lets say S3) to cluster for merging with fresh data, which will take too much time as its huge in volume and also after processing,again it is to be stored in S3.

Please suggest, which kind of EMR cluster will be suitable here...